# Finding missing emails in SQL Server

Tags: sql, join, anti-join

I am trying to do something I've done a million times and it's not working, can anyone tell me why?

I have a table for people who sent in resumes, and it has their email address in it...

I want to find out if any of these people have NOT signed up on the web site. The aspnet_Membership table has all the people who ARE signed up on the web site.

There are 9472 job seekers, with unique email addresses.

This query produces 1793 results:

```
select j.email from jobseeker j
join aspnet_Membership m on j.email = m.email
```

This suggests that there should be 7679 (9472-1793) emails of people who are not signed up on the web site. Since 1793 of them DID match, I would expect the rest of them DON'T match... but when I do the query for that, I get nothing!

Why is this query giving me nothing???

```
select j.email 
from jobseeker j
where j.email not in (select email from aspnet_Membership)
```

I don't know how that could be not working - it basically says "show me all the emails which are IN the jobseeker table, but NOT IN the aspnet_Membership table...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had a very similar problem recently where the subquery was returning null values sometimes.  Then, the in statement treats null in a weird way, I think always matching the value, so if you change your query to:

```
select j.email 
from jobseeker j
where j.email not in (select email from aspnet_Membership
                      where email is not null)
```

it may work....

Answer (score 2):

You could have a lot of duplicates out there.  I'm not seeing the query error off the top of my head, but you might try writing it this way:

```
SELECT j.email
FROM jobseeker j
LEFT JOIN aspnet_Membership m ON m.email = j.email
WHERE m.email IS NULL
```

You might also throw a GROUP BY or DISTINCT in there to get rid of duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Also see [Five ways to return all rows from one table which are not in another table](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/5_ways_to_return_rows_from_one_table_not_in_another_table)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `exists` instead of `in` like this:

```
Select J.Email
From Jobseeker j
Where not exists (Select * From aspnetMembership a where j.email = a.email)
```

You should get better performance and avoid the 'weird' behaviour (which I suspect is to do with null values/results) when using `in`.